# Alternatives to creating a Compound Control by extending a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to create a custom Compound Control in Android that holds some logic. For the purpose of this example, let's say I want it to switch between two views when clicked.

According to the [API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound), it looks like the way to do that is to create a new class that extends Layout, and do everything in there.

So I did just that:

- I created a XML layout to inflate for my custom component:

.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="World"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

- Then I created my custom Layout class, and added the logic in there:

  public class MyWidget extends RelativeLayout {
      public final View mView1;
      public final View mView2;

  ```
  public MyWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_widget, this, true);
      mView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
      mView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view2);

      view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              switchViews();
          }
      });
  }

  public void switchViews() {
      if (mView1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
          mView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
          mView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      if (mView2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
          mView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
          mView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- And finally, I included my custom view in some layout:

.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.example.MyWidget
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout
```

And that works.

I am not completely happy with that solution though, for 2 reasons:

- In the constructor of MyWidget, I instantiate 2 nested `RelativeLayout` by calling the `super()` constructor, and the one that is at the root of my XML layout. For that, I know I can instead use `<merge>` as my XML root and that gets me rid of the extra `RelativeLayout`. Except that defining XML attributes, such as `android:background` on my `<merge>` tag doesn't have any effect, so I have to define it programmatically, which is not as nice.
- The custom View is a subclass of RelativeLayout, and therefore expose methods it inherits from it, such as `addView()`, even if it doesn't make sense to add child views to it. I know I can override those methods to prevent users from doing that, but I would still find it cleaner to inherit from View.

Comment: For complex controls extending View or ViewGroup is often a good option, but for simple controls like your example it would likely involve a lot of unnecessary work.

For the TextView example you've given I would extend TextView and create methods to handle a second text string etc. Have a read through the [TextView source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView) to see how the functionality you want to duplicate has been implemented.